# How do I add a GestureOverlayView programmatically?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-relativelayout

This is likely to be a very novice question, but I'm having trouble adding a GestureOverlayView programmatically.  I have a basic hello world app going that I'm experimenting with before merging with my real app.  Frankly I'm a bit over my head since this will be my first Android app.

Anyways, getting along with the code, my fragment_main.xml looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 tools:context="pha.viz.gesturetest.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

 <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And my MainActivity.java right now is:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private GestureLibrary mLibrary;
    RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_layout);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);



        mLibrary = GestureLibraries.fromRawResource(this, R.raw.gestures);
        mLibrary.load();
        GestureOverlayView gestures = new GestureOverlayView(this);
        gestures.setGestureStrokeAngleThreshold(90.0f);
        gestures.addOnGesturePerformedListener(handleGestureListener);

        mRelativeLayout.addView(gestures);

        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 

        LayoutParams params = gestures.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = display.getWidth() / 2;
        gestures.setLayoutParams(params);
        gestures.setTranslationX(0);
        }

    private OnGesturePerformedListener handleGestureListener = new
            OnGesturePerformedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView overlay, Gesture gesture) {
            ArrayList<Prediction> predictions = mLibrary.recognize(gesture);
            // one prediction needed
            if (predictions.size() > 0) {
                Prediction prediction = predictions.get(0);
                // checking prediction
                if (prediction.score > 1.0) {
                    // and action
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), prediction.name,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }       
        }
    };


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

The issue is that it's going into a crash.  Admittedly I'm following the same steps I would with a TextView, and I assumed it would work, so I may be missing something quite obvious.

I am also aware the the code works if I am manually adding the GestureOverlayView onto the fragment_main.xml and just referring to it within the MainActivity, but the moment I try to change it to create a "new" GestureOverlayView in the code and add it to my RelativeLayout, it crashes.

Thank you for reading all this, I appreciate any help or insight you may give me.

PS.  I thought it might interest some of you as to WHY I am going through the hassle of doing this programmatically rather than through the XML file.  The reason is that I am trying to recognize a large number of gestures rapidly.  I found with another test file that having a single GestureOverlayView was slow, you would recognize them one at a time.  However, side by side, they would be able to create predictions simultaneously, giving the illusion of "faster".  With a bit of work, I am hoping to create additional GestureOverlayViews on touch, and destroy them once the command is complete.  But I couldn't even get through the obvious in this simple test, which is the creation of the view.

Comment: Post your logcat error.

Comment: 06-29 21:38:31.194: E/AndroidRuntime(31152): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-29 21:38:31.194: E/AndroidRuntime(31152):  at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java)
06-29 21:38:31.194: E/AndroidRuntime(31152):  at pha.viz.gesturetest.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:28)
06-29 21:38:31.194: E/AndroidRuntime(31152):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
06-29 21:38:31.194: E/AndroidRuntime(31152):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
06-29 21:38:31.194: E/AndroidRuntime(31152):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java)

Comment: Thank you for responding so quickly, I've isolated the relevant section given the limited characters.  I also googled how to use the logcat.  :P  If there is anything missing, I can attach a file.  I'm not sure how the logcat is normally attached here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a `NullPointerException`. A null pointer exception on a line of the form A.B.C means that something on the left-hand side of a dot is null. This in your case seem to be appearing in line 28 of MainActivity. Seem like it can not find the view by id. Either your Id is mispelled. Please check it.

Comment: Thank you, it was because I created created the relativelayout variable outside the oncreate method, assuming it'd come first.  It didn't, so a simple move into the oncreate method solved everything.  I appreciate your help!